# Get child's form.$invalid from parent component

Tags: angularjs

I have a parent component in Angular.js that has a child component. The child has a form, and the parent has a button that will be enabled/disabled depending on the validity of the child's form.

What is the best way to do it?

I already have a working solution, but it involves a two-way binding variable, and I wonder if there is an easier way using a one-way variable.

In the child I have this:

```
module.component("personEdit", {
    bindings: {
        personForm: "="
    },
    template: `<form name="$ctrl.personForm" ...>
                    <input name="phone" required />
               </form>`
});
```

And in the parent I have this:

```
module.component("directoryEdit", {
    template: `<person-edit person-form="$ctrl.personForm"></person-edit>
               <button ng-disabled="$ctrl.personForm.$invalid">`
});
```

Note that the parent doesn't initialize a `$ctrl.personForm` variable, it actually gets initialized in the children (that's done "magically" by Angular.js), and is passed back to the parent because of the two-way binding.

Is it possible to avoid passing that variable into the children and instead query the `$invalid` field using something like `$ctrl.allForms['form-name'].$invalid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it like this in child component:

```
module.component("personEdit", {
    bindings: {
        onValidityChange: "&"
    },
    template: `<form name="$ctrl.personForm" ...>
                    <input name="phone" required />
               </form>`
});
```

...

```
$scope.$watch('$ctrl.personForm.$valid', function(value) {
  vm.onValidityChange({valid: value});
})
```

Now in parent you can use this callback:

```
<person-edit on-validity-change="$ctrl.onChildValidityChange(valid)"
```

...
    vm.onChildValidityChange = function(x) {
      vm.childValid = x;
    }

P.S. Seems a bit complicated, but in this case your components are fully independent.